# Get the correct url format to Facebook Sharer

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, url, escaping, facebook-sharer

I need to format a url passed to Facebook Sharer via AS3 using `navigateToURL(new URLRequest(request), "_blank");`.

The url that is passed has a lot of strange characters. What is the best way to get the correct output?

This works:
[http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.somesiteurlthatdoesnotexist.com?title=This works fine](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.somesiteurlthatdoesnotexist.com?title=This%20works%20fine)

**This does not work:**
[http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.somesiteurlthatdoesnotexist.com?title=Jag behöver fixa en url som funkar med åäl och & tecken](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.somesiteurlthatdoesnotexist.com?title=Jag%20beh%C3%B6ver%20fixa%20en%20url%20som%20funkar%20med%20%C3%A5%C3%A4l%20och%20&%20tecken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

escape("Jag behöver fixa en url som funkar med åäl och & tecken");

It should make it "URL encoded".

Comment: Yep! It will encode it to "%26". This is then decoded back into "&" by the server/browser.